# Mongodb Query for elements in a sub-document which match a condition

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document that looks something like this:

```
{ 
    "spans" : [
        {
            "from" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "to" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "from" : ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "to" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "from" : ISODate("2016-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "to" : ISODate("2016-02-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query for a document but only return spans with a from greater than 2016-1-2

I first tried $elemMatch but it only returns the first matching span.

It seems like the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator is the right way to do this but I cant seem to find any methods on the ProjectionBuilder to do a filter.

I think I want to do a query like this:

```
.aggregate([
   {
       $match:{/*Some other filter*/}
   },
   {
      $project: {
         Spans: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$spans",
               as: "span",
               cond: {  $gt: [ "$$span.from", ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z")  ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

I think it should look like this but there is no filter method

```
        var pb = new ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<MyObj>();

        var projection = pb.Combine(new List<ProjectionDefinition<MyObj>> {
            pb.Filter(x => x.Spans, s => s.From > from))//no such thing...
        });


        var result= _collection.
            .Match(x=>/*my match*/)
            .Project<MyObj>(projection)
            .ToList();
```

What am I missing? Is it something other than the ProjectionBuilder I should be using?

Comment: Does your sample contains data as date? It appears non date data.

Comment: @Saleem yes its a date in the actual database ill update my JSON

Comment: Your sample data contains invalid ISO dates :) date should be two digit format.

Comment: @Salem sorry I'm writing this out manually, my actual data is slightly different

Comment: I have updated my answer with two solutions. I'd suggest to compare numbers to test which one is performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two, may be more ways to solve this problem. You can use `$project` with `$filter` or plain old and trusty `$unwind`.

I'm coding an example using shell query and quite sure you can easily translate into C#.

**Solution #1**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$spans"},
  {$match: {"spans.from": {$gt: ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000+0000")}}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id", spans:{$push:"$spans"}}}
])
```

**Solution #2** Supported on MongoDB version 3.2+ only

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: 
    {spans:
      {$filter:
        {input:"$spans", as: "spans", cond:
          {$gt: ["$$spans.from", ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000+0000")]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Examples above will filter out all array elements less than or equals to `ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000+0000")` in `from` leaving end result as:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804123984d3eb497d538a6e"), 
    "spans" : [
        {
            "from" : ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "to" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "from" : ISODate("2016-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "to" : ISODate("2016-02-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The filter query does work if i do it directly in the database, i just cant seem to find the relevant c# methods to perform it, Unwind does seem to be there Ill give that a go and see if i can get that going. My understanding from reading is that unwind is slower than filter, is this the case?

Comment: Indeed `$unwind` is not efficient as `$project/$filter` but it works on most of mongodb versions. What is your mongodb version?

Comment: Also `C#` driver is lacking some feature. I have created a ticket in past. see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1585

Comment: Ahh yup, when they say use a BSON document does this mean I could just pass the query as a string? How could I do that?

Comment: maybe thats the way to go then, it seems like the filter isnt supported yet in C# but its the best way for latest mongo. Ill give that a try

Comment: filters are supported but not nested one.